# LockModule.init undefined error in auth0 react-android getting started

Tags: auth0, react-native

I'm following the instructions to get auth0 running in react-native android https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native-android

And I am getting the following error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'LockModule.init') show auth0-lock.js:33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implies that the `LockModule` variable is undefined; by checking the code for `auth0-lock.js` we can see that the variable is being initialized by the following logic:

```
var { NativeModules, Platform } = require('react-native');
var LockModule = NativeModules.Auth0LockModule;
```

According to [react-native documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#register-the-module) in order to use a module implemented as a native module you need to register it.

> The package needs to be provided in the `getPackages` method of the MainApplication.java file. This file exists under the android folder in your react-native application directory.

You should have something similar to:

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new LockReactPackage()
        );
}
```

If this is not the root cause of the issue you'll need to update your question with more details.

Comment: That did it - adding the import statement `import com.auth0.lock.react.LockReactPackage;` and returning the package worked.  Looks like the getting started instructions from Auth0 are missing a few steps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to get Auth0 working on iOS.  Our fix is here (react-native run-ios to see more detailed messages for the issue; correct header search paths; update podfile with OneSignal; add OneSignal library)

https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/133